Comparison of effectiveness of 3 different drugs
I am doing a drug field trial for 3 different drugs to measure their efficacy/effectiveness. Each drug was given to it's own group of animals only. The parameter of interest was measured before and after drug intervention in the individual animals. I used a paired T test to compare the mean differences between the pre and post-treatment for each drug in their respective groups. My supervisor wants me to statistically compare which of the 3 drugs is most effective. Which test can I use? PS: am not good at statistics

This does not appear to be the right design to answer your question.  It is valid only for assessing whether there is a within-treatment time trend.  If you want to compare treatments you should have randomized animals to treatments.

Running 3 paired t-tests (as I assume this is what you did?) is not the right approach, but it was a step in the right direction.
A paired t-test for drug A will tell you if drug A had overall a positive effect (whether the parameter of interest moved in the "right" direction, to statistically significant extent). The paired t-tests computes the "average change" of said parameter (let's call this parameter $P$, and that change between pre and post $\Delta P$, and let's assume, w/o losing any generality, that a larger $\Delta P$ corresponds to a "better" effect of the drug). Now, you could look at all 3 values of $\Delta p$, and see which is the largest, but that is not proper statistical analysis.
Instead, what you should do is compute all the paired differences for each drug; $P_{post}A - P_{pre}A$ for all pairs for drug A, and the same for the other 2 drugs. Call these new variables $\Delta P_A, \Delta P_B$, etc. Then run an ANOVA test, to compare the means of these 3 changes, accross the 3 drugs (please use the "Welch ANOVA", to avoid issue with unequal variances). If the result is significant, then at least 1 drug had a statistically significantly different effect than at least another one. Then you should run a post-hoc test after this significant ANOVA, to find out which is "the best". If you used a Welch ANOVA, Games-Howell is the preferred post-Hoc test. You can find a good description of ANOVA, post-hoc tests, etc.
Now, if your initial ANOVA test was not significant, that would mean none of the drugs acted significantly different from each other; it could be because the 3 drugs are similar (in their effect), or it could be because your sample size was not large enough (not enough animals in each group) to be able to detect a significant difference.
Given that you only have 3 drugs, and that you are interested in "the best", you could also decide to simply run 2 (non-paired) t-tests (please use the Welch flavor, to handle the problems with unequal variances), comparing "the best" to the other 2, and you can even decide to run these 2 tests single-sided, to further preserve power. Use a simple Bonferroni correction (in this case use $\frac {\alpha} {2}$) to handle the multiple comparison issue. This should give you very similar results to ANOVA + Games-Howell (except that Games-Howell is double sided; but you can "trick" it by using $2\alpha$ for significance).
You will need some software to run the tests (Welch ANOVA, Games Howell post-hoc, and/or Welch t-test). R, Python, SPSS, Minitab, Matlab, etc. If you do not have access to such tools, or are not familiar with them, I would recommend Real Statistics; it is a free add-on to Excel, with very good online guides, tutorials, examples, etc.
Final note. ANOVA (or the t-tests) have assumptions which you should check, before being too attached to the results, the most critical being normality of the residuals.

This has of been help  thank-you. The new variables are negative due to the reduction effect. Do I change to postive or analyse them as they are?

The new variables represent the effect of the drug on the variable of interest (outcome). Is it moving in the (negative) direction you expected? (e.g. drug reduces cholesterol, or blood pressure). Then analyze as they are, and low for the largest negative change. If instead the drugs made things worse, then that is pretty much all you need to report... In other words, if "better drug" means larger reduction in outcome, leave as is; you can do ANOVA, t-tests etc. just the same.

The drug was moving to the negative as expected. I did use a welch anova test for comparison of the 2 new variables.  Thanks alot for your help

Feel free to upvote them...
